# Ошибка компиляции gcc программы с графикой

Tags: linux, c, ubuntu, gcc

Поставил libgraph, чтобы можно было компилировать программы, в которых используется хэдер . Но при компиляции выводит ошибку.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <graphics.h>

void Draw(int x, int y, int color) {
    setfillstyle(1, color);
    bar (x, y, x+20, y+20);
}

int main() {
    int x, y;
    int gd = DETECT,gm; 
    initgraph (& gd,& gm,NULL);
    setfillstyle(1, COLOR(0, 0, 255));
    bar(0, 0, 399, 399);
    x = 0; y = 240;
    while (x + 20 < 400){
        if ( kbhit() )
            if ( getch() == 27 ) break;
    Draw(x, y, COLOR(255, 255, 0));
    delay(20);
    Draw(x, y, COLOR(0,0,255));
    x++;
    }
    closegraph();

    return 0;
}
```

Ошибка при компиляции

```
    draw.c: In function ‘Draw’:
draw.c:5:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘setfillstyle’; did you mean ‘setlinestyle’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     setfillstyle(1, color);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
     setlinestyle
draw.c: In function ‘main’:
draw.c:13:21: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘COLOR’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     setlinestyle(1, COLOR(0, 0, 255));
                     ^~~~~
draw.c:13:5: error: too few arguments to function ‘setlinestyle’
     setlinestyle(1, COLOR(0, 0, 255));
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/include/graphics.h:117:0,
                 from draw.c:2:
/usr/local/include/shapes.h:109:6: note: declared here
 void setlinestyle (int linestyle, int upattern, int thickness);
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
draw.c:17:14: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘kbhit’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         if ( kbhit() )
```

ОС: Linux Ubuntu

P.S. Программа написана как в учебнике Полякова

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/525051/how-do-i-use-graphics-h-in-ubuntu

Comment: Выкидывайте `graphics.h` и полякова и используйте нормальную графику.

Comment: Эти сообщения говорят о том, что в файле *graphics.h* отсутствуют объявления функций *setfillstyle*  и иже с ними. По простому: файл хидера от другой программы.

Comment: Может я и не прав, но лучше OpenG займитесь если хотите что-то рисовать)))) а это не библиотека дичь